# A problem on completeness of a specific space of complex functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $C(D) \cap H(\bar D)$ denote the inner product space of functions these are analytic in unit disk $D$ and continuous in $\bar D$, equipped with the inner product $(f,g)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(e^{i \theta}) \overline {g(e^{i \theta})} d \theta$, is it a Hilbert space?

Comment: It's just the $L^2$ inner product of $f$ and $g$ restricted on $\partial D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not complete. Completion of this space is called $H^2(D)$.
It consists of all analytic functions for which
$$\| f\|^2:=\sup_r\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$$
is finite, or alternatively
$$f(z)=\sum_0^\infty a_nz^n,\quad \sum_0^\infty|a_n|^2<\infty,$$
or alternatively, all those function in $L_2(-\pi,\pi)$ whose negative Fourier
coefficients vanish.

For an example of a function which is in $H^2$ but not continuous in the closed disk, take $$\exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$$
which is bounded in the unit disk, therefore belongs to $H^2$ but is not
continuous because the boundary values have absolute value $1$ except at $z=1$
where the radial limit is $0$.

Comment: You still need to give an example of a function in $H^2(D)$ which is not in the space $C(D)\cap H(\bar D)$.

Comment: @Antonius: I gave the example.

Comment: Thank you and I think I need to study the theory of Hardy spaces carefully.